# Pivot millons of records

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table with 4 columns and more than 100 million records. 
Table Design:

```
ID char(12) PK 
Type Char(2) PK (Values 1,2,3)
DCID varchar(10) Null
IND Varchar(2) Null (Values Y, N)
```

This needs to be pivoted like

```
ID, DCID1, DCID2, DCID3, IND1, IND2, IND3
```

If Type is having value 1,Then in the Pivoted table the `DCID1` should have the value or if Type is 2 `DCID2` should have the value and so on. Also correspoding `IND` also needs to be placed in `IND1`, `IND2`, `IND3` like that.

How to pivot this?

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion would be to look at using both the UNPIVOT and the PIVOT functions to get the result.

The UNPIVOT will be used to convert the `DCI` and `IND` multiple columns into multiple rows in a single column. Once that is done, then you can pivot the data back into columns.

The UNPIVOT code will be similar to this:

```
select id,
  col +type as new_col,
  value
from
(
  select id,
    type, 
    dcid, 
    cast(ind as varchar(10)) ind
  from yt
) d
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (DCID, IND)
) unpiv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d483e/6). This gives a result:

```
|           ID | NEW_COL | VALUE |
----------------------------------
| 1            |  dcid1  |  test |
| 1            |   ind1  |     Y |
| 2            |  dcid2  |   est |
| 2            |   ind2  |     Y |
```

The `new_col` contains the `DCID` and `IND` names and it has the `type` value concatenated to the end.  This new value will be what you apply the PIVOT to:

```
select id, DCID1, DCID2, DCID3, IND1, IND2, IND3
from
(
  select id,
    col +type as new_col,
    value
  from
  (
    select id,
      type, 
      dcid, 
      cast(ind as varchar(10)) ind
    from yt
  ) d
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (DCID, IND)
  ) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for new_col in (DCID1, DCID2, DCID3, IND1, IND2, IND3)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d483e/7). The result will be:

```
|           ID | DCID1 | DCID2 | DCID3 | IND1 | IND2 | IND3 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 1            |  test |       |       |    Y |      |      |
| 2            |       |   est |       |      |    Y |      |
| 3            |       |       |  blah |      |      |    Y |
| 4            |   yes |       |       |    N |      |      |
| 5            |       |    hs |       |      |    N |      |
| 6            |       |       |    jr |      |      |    N |
```

Comment: I have already unpivoted and I have ID, Type, DCID, IND in my table and it has more than 100 million records. while I Pivot again I am getting Out of memory exception error after getting 10 million records (pivoted). May I know which is the best way to pivot these many records?

Comment: @AnandMuthiah Right, this further unpivots the `DCID` and `IND` into the same column.